# Loading different data with Loader

Tags: java, android, loader

There is an abstract class of the fragment that will inherit the other fragments. They will all be the same, except for one thing - they will load different data.

```
public abstract class MovieFragment extends Fragment
                                        implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<Movie>> {

protected abstract List<Movie> getMovies(int currentPage);

//fragment implementation body

private static class MovieLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<List<Movie>> {

        public MovieLoader(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStartLoading() {
            forceLoad();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStopLoading(){
            cancelLoad();
        }

        @Override
        public List<Movie> loadInBackground() {
            return getMovies(3);
        }
      }
    }
```

Tried it like that, but since MovieLoader should be static then it's not possible to use getMovies (int currentPage). Advise how to implement?
Implementation of a class that inherits the abstract class MovieFragment (for example):

```
public class PopularMovieFragment extends MovieFragment {

    public static Fragment getInstance(){
        return new PopularMovieFragment();
    }

    @Override
    protected List<Movie> getMovies(int currentPage) {
        return new MovieFetch().getPopularMovies();
    }
}
```

Comment: you forgot to ask your question

Comment: @pskink, i fix it